# jDateChoose not working

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I am using a jDate Chooser in a Java Project of mine
I am required to retrieve the date from the jDateChooser and put it into mySQL table
the methods i have used are `newBirthDate=(Date)inBirthDate.getDate();`
newBirthDate is a date variable (data type defined earlier)
and inBirthDate is the datechooser

then, i have simply put it into mysql
i am getting that huge and uncomprehensible exception in the output pane
and i am not getting what to do
pls help 
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUbOh.jpg)

EDIT :
the exception

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at newUser.FormValidation(newUser.java:115)
    at newUser.jButton2ActionPerformed(newUser.java:589)
    at newUser.access$700(newUser.java:15)
    at newUser$8.actionPerformed(newUser.java:537)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 42 seconds)
```

Comment: You need to change `desiredRoom` to be a java.util.Date.  You can also use the `getTime()` method on this Date to be used in the creation of the java.sql.Date if ncessary for insertion into your DB

Comment: You'd better learn how to read and understand these "huge and uncomprehensible exceptions". They contain the exact problem and position where it happens.

Comment: where the problem is..is known
the problem is also known
how to solve it is not known

Comment: im sorry.i did read them
except what exactly is this desired room can u explain?

Comment: `newBirthDate` should be a java.util.Date

Comment: it is a java.util.Date

Comment: What is `Date`? Did you import `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: it is java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the date taken from the datechooser as a `java.util.Date`
then use this to convert into `java.sql.Date` and then insert into mysql:

```
sqlDate= new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

thanks everyone for the help :)